# Css attributes changes are not responding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following div:

```
<div class="order-data col-xs-2 col-md-3">
```

In a css file, The attributes for this div were the following:

```
div.container>div.container-striped>div.row>div.order-data {
 min-height: 30px;
 line-height: 4em;
 line-height: 20px;
}
```

I changed order-data attributes for this:

```
div.container>div.container-striped>div.row>div.order-data{
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I am saving It but when I reload the page, the changes are not responding. What is that?

Comment: please could you reproduce the issue in a simple fiddle?

Comment: Hi, no i cant, the css is too long

Comment: if your html looks the same like in this fiddle it works: http://jsfiddle.net/dw2u3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can clear the cache of the browser and check

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-striped">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="order-data col-xs-2 col-md-3"> 
       test test    
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container>div.container-striped>div.row>div.order-data{
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
    background-color:red;
}
```

**DEMo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4V5PH/

Comment: Yeah I understand. My problem is that, when I use the inspect, the changes are not did.

Comment: When I do the changes by "style" It works, but not in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

this problems almost me too face when i update css file it wont update in HTML file when reload its because of cache you can do simply use your updated css code in HTML file using

```
<style>
div.container>div.container-striped>div.row>div.order-data{
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the css file. This appears to be a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the styles has been override somewhere else after you've set those styles or maybe in `javascript`. I suggest you to use `firebug` or chrome inspect tool to figure it out.

You can also try to use `!important` attribute here:

```
div.container>div.container-striped>div.row>div.order-data{
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: @nandophillips did you try to clear the browser cache? did you include your file correctly?

Comment: The file is correctly included. Maybe is the cache. How can i clear it?